# jQuery popstate event handling in firefox

Tags: jquery, events, firefox, google-chrome, popstate

I have got something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(window).bind('popstate', function () { do sth;});
});
```

It works like a charm in chrome, but doesn't work in FF (event handler is not fired). When I take this code outside the ready block, the event can be handled, but I don't like it being outside ready block.

Do you know any solutions?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, just did window.onpopstate = function () {} :)